# What are the chances of winning a tournament of a fixed number of games if I know the player's win rate in all games he plays

Tags: probability

A player has a historic success rate of winning 2/3 of games he plays.
He enters a series of tournaments, all 5 rounds each...1st round, 2nd round, quarters, semis, final.
How often on average will he win a tournament?

My theory... 0.66x0.66x0.66x0.66x0.66 is chance of winning particular tournament ie 0.125 ... therefore he wins on average one in 8 tournaments entered.

Comment: So each player gets to play max 5 times?

Comment: $\left(\frac23\right)^5 \approx 0.1317$ so a bit more than one in eight.

Comment: You are assuming that each round is equally difficult and independent of the others - you would get a different answer if this player always won in rounds $1$ and $2$ thanks to seeding against weaker players and always lost in round $3$ against a better player